# Fatal error message

Tags: magento-1.9, fatal-error, compiler

I manage my website with *magento* but I tried to connect to my page and I have the following message ;

> Fatal error: **Class 'Mage_ConfigurableSwatches_Helper_Data' not found in /home/jmellman/public_html/app/Mage.php on line 547**

It happened just after I try to upload files from an extension and I flushed the cache and enable compilation but when I refreshed the page I had the message.

How to fix the problem ?

Comment: This is not a solution, but try to go to `app/etc/modules/` and find the `.xml` file of the module that you tried to install. If it is named `yourmodule.xml` just rename it `yourmodule.xml.tmp` (this should disable the extension) and see if you can access the frontend again. I think something went wrong with your module installation. Tell us how you installed it.

Comment: In extension user guide I followed the steps;I upload the files and I had to flush the cache and if necessary enable compilation and when I did that I refresh the page and the fatal error message appeared. So I don t want the extension anymore if it is causing such problem. I have to launch my website and I need to find where is the error but i don t have the expertise in code editing php etc

Comment: have you  used any extension  name like ConfigurableSwatches?

Comment: I wanted to upload a extension for managing shipping rate tables and I don t even understand what configurable swatches is > I don use it and I don t want it. I prefer to remove all traces of the extension and have my website running again because I am anxious

Comment: Can you access your Admin Panel? If yes, then disable the compiler again. Did you use FTP to upload the files?

Comment: I can t access the backend> I can only access my cpanel where all the files and folders are and I upload manually without a FTP client

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your code is loading disabled module.
So, when Magento didn't find proper module by module name it'll try to load Mage_Modulename_...

I'd suggest to disable compilation at first, clean up your cache and check this problem out.

If it's happened again try to disable module in your uploaded extension.
Find file of your module:

```
MAGEDIR/app/etc/modules/Your_Module.xml
```

replace

```
<active>true</active>
```

with

```
<active>false</active>
```

And clean up Magento cache.

MAGEDIR - it means path to root of Magento on your server.

Comment: I delete all the files of var/cache ? even if those files are called mage? I am sorry I am a neophyte in this domain and I could really use some help!

Comment: :) Could you get a filename from the extension package in etc/module folder? Try to find the same file in the MagentoDIR/app/etc/modules folder.

Comment: By the way, what is the name of the extension which you've uploaded?

Comment: The name is Shipping Table rates by Amasty.But I don t want it anymore if it s to have those issues I can t handle myself. I payed 90 dollars for that and I have problems. So I removed the files of my cpanel but it didn t change the problem. I am desperate

Comment: Ok, could find string "ConfigurableSwatches" in your Magento files and show the list?

Comment: Amasty extensions usually include two steps to install. Did you perform both steps?

Comment: Yes But I don t understand the process. I upload step 1 files and then Step 2. I didnt do anything between the two steps

Comment: @ForMat, seem, it's NOT a problem of this module. I'm pretty sure that there are uses of disabled or removed module. Magento showed it just after clean up the cache...

Comment: What do I have to do to have my website running again and to not to have the 'fatal error: Class 'Mage_ConfigurableSwatches_Helper_Data' not found in /home/jmellman/public_html/app/Mage.php on line 547"?

Comment: No, Amasty modules are fine. I think it is incorrect installation. My guess is that Magento compiler was enabled during installing. @AudreyDURAND I have good experience with Amasty support. You could contact them and they should be able to help out.

Comment: @ForMat, yeah, agree. I've missed "not". :)

Comment: Audrey, could you edit file includes/config.php and put "#" before "define"?
This will disable compilation.

By the way, have an access to Admin Panel?

Answer (score 2):

The class `Mage_ConfigurableSwatches_Helper_Data` was implemented in Magento 1.9.1.0

It appears that some extension or theme is calling that class and it's not present in your installation (due to a legacy version). Please check your Magento version to be sure it is at least 1.9.1.0.

If you have a previous version, be sure you have copied the patch files provided by the theme or extension vendor.

Answer (score 1):

Below are multiple solutions:

1. You need to create helper (`Data.php`) class is unavailable inside `Mage_ConfigurableSwatches`

   ```
   class Mage_ConfigurableSwatches_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
   {

   }
   ```

   And need to add in module `config.xml` file

   ```
   <global>
       <helpers>
           <configurableSwatches>
               <class>Mage_ConfigurableSwatches_Helper</class>
           </configurableSwatches>
       </helpers>
   </global>
   ```
2. If you can't get into the admin interface but have SSH access you can disable it there with:

   ```
   php -f shell/compiler.php -- disable

   php -f shell/compiler.php -- clear

   php -f shell/compiler.php -- state
   ```